# Does Reika return later in the series?

Tags: victory-kickoff

At the end of episode 22 of *Ginga e Kickoff!*, we see that Reika, after a devastating game, has come down with a fever and is being cared for by her parents at home indefinitely.

[image: Reika at home in bed]

Watching episode 23, we barely hear anything about her, except that she has gone off to her family's villa.

[image: "Reika-chan is going to her villa."]

Does Reika return later in the series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, She does come back in Episode 26 . They go to her villa to train I think.

Here is the plot for that episode. Hope this helps

http://gingaekickoff.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_26